# How to make the activity react to clicks if the BottomSheetFragment is visible?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I really need your help
My task is to make BottomSheetFragment that cannot be closed  when user clicks or touches outside and the background Activity can responds to clicks.
My activity has a player and at one moment BottomSheetFragment appears under it. Without closing the BottomSheetFragment, I need the user to be able to click on the player (which is still visible) and play the stream.
How I can reach this?